# Open Com port and send Hexadecimal Bytes from windows Command Prompt

Tags: windows-7, command-line, hex, decimal, command-prompt

I need to write a batch file to open a com port and send decimal or hexadecimal commands to a com port.  I can write this file if I know the commands and formats for windows command prompt to open the com port and send decimal or hexadecimal formatted bytes.  If anyone knows how to do this please chime in.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to : http://www.virtualblueness.net/asem51/bbatch.htm

Open the Com Port (adjust com port settings as needed):

```
MODE COMX:9600,N,8,1,P
```

Wait a little bit

```
SLEEP 9600
```

%1 is a paramater, i.e your hex file

```
COPY %1.HEX COMX
```